# iis and apache combination on real server for 403

Tags: apache, iis, web

We have a win2003 server that run both IIS 7 and apache (using wamp server 2.2).

We put on both server a page named test.html that show us a message that say "You are on IIS page" and "You are on WAMP page" to show us if everything is working correctly.

Both running real great locally. IIS is listening on port 80 and apache on port 8082. The problems come remotly. Both services are running and wamp is fully online (green icon + "put online" option activate).

Locally, on the server, doing `http://localhost/test.html` and `http://localhost:8082/test.html` show the correct pages. If we replace localhost by real IP address (for example purpose, let say `http://10.2.5.16/test.html` and `http://10.2.5.16:8082/test.html`), still work. (not actual address but address used for real is the same used by dns web service)

Remotly, from any other PC, doing `http://10.2.5.16/test.html` and `http://10.2.5.16:8082/test.html`, the first give us the website normally, the second give us a HTTP 403 FORBIDEN (tried using both htaccess and windows permission, still have 403). The same way, using `http://www.ourdomain.com/test.html` and `http://www.ourdomain.com:8082/test.html` give us the exact same result (first ok, second 403)

Is it possible to make it work correctly?

Thanks in advance.

edit: Just to add to the solution :

1. the firewall was blocking me, add the wamp on this port allowed
2. in my configuration, i had in my directory statement Require local, which needed to be set to Require all granted

for the rest, the solution was pretty it.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can get to the sites locally tells me both servers are setup correctly and listening on respective ports.

Upon further questions, the OP indicated that the Servername Directive, is pointing to localhost and it should be changed as.

```
ServerName localhost:8082
```

To

```
ServerName example.com:8082 # or add "ServerAlias example.com:8082" to your existing.
```

Where as example.com is your site DNS. Then in your [System32\drivers\etc\hosts] point that DNS to the ip of your Remote host.

403 is happening because the request from the remote is not matched against any Servername or ServerAlias and it falls to the default handler which normally has stricket permissions. If you look closely in logs(/logs/apache/access.log), there should be something about "access denied by server configuration /somelocation like your default DocRoot"

If you make request for http://example.com and you have correct ip in your hostfile, you can trace what happens to that request in the remote host and where it ends up(firewalls, Apache etc). Apache is good at logging and you just need to find relevant log entries!

Comment: No, that's one of the first thing I checked. Both .htaccess and winpermission are set to let full read and execute access in the folder itself and file properties and no forbid or deny stuff set from apache (nor iis even if it isn't supposed to interact at this level)

Comment: What's in your Apache "Listen" directive" and can you in your Apache folder  "grep -ir "[F]" .". I would think, there has to be something to correspond to that 403 served.

Comment: Listen 8082 and
ServerName localhost:8082 .
since i'm on windows, I can't "grep" but using the closest command in windows don't give me any conclusive results.

Comment: That's probably it: Your "ServerName" Directive should match your DNS or sitename and hence that's why it works in localhost. See updated answer.

Comment: making some test. Still work locally (as it always did) but still not able to connect from another pc. seems to me like iis grab every incoming connexion no matter if other things are listening (in this case, wamp server)

Comment: For the IIS thing: It should server only sites that match its host headers and ports given for the site. Stop IIS and WWW service if you want check that out and see where request end up.

Comment: ok you are right, something bad is happening here. The block don't come from IIS. I stopped the service and put wamp on port 80 and still can't access remotely. I'll check further within...

Comment: but still not working... I'll accept if I can actually make it works

Comment: 2 things... 1. the firewall was blocking me, add the wamp on this port allowed  2. in my configuration, i had in my directory statement Require local, which needed to be set to Require all granted